# cmd-w to close pinned tabs

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close pinned tabs in Safari?

I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> like for normal tabs but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I'd set up a *keyboard shortcut* in **Safari** for both **Pin Tab** and **Unpin Tab** to the same *shortcut*, e.g., **⌥⌘P** and then you can toggle the pinned status of the **Tab** with the same *keyboard shortcut*.

This way when a **Tab** is pinned and you want to close it, using the keyboard, you'd first press, e.g., **⌥⌘P** then: **⌘W**

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

[image]

Comment: This works for now. It's also convenient to have a shortcut to pin and unpin, thanks for this solution.